# Why is using a list subscription allowed in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax

How is the following construct accepted in Python:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i, l[i] in enumerate(l[:]):
    print(l[i])
```

There seem to be no complaints and it happily prints out `1 2 3 4`. How is this allowed and what exactly does it do?

Comment: @johnsharpe how on earth did you find it? I was looking for a solid 20 minutes but couldn't find anything! :-)

Comment: I Googled *"python subscription in for loop target list"*, it was the sixth hit.

Comment: Well I certainly missed it. Ah well, another sign-post it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax rule for `for` loops](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) allows the iteration variables to be any of those specified in `target_list`:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

where [`target_list` allows](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for the following constructs:

```
target_list     ::=  target ("," target)* [","]
target          ::=  identifier
                     | "(" [target_list] ")"
                     | "[" [target_list] "]"
                     | attributeref
                     | subscription
                     | slicing
                     | "*" target
```

This means you can also do other wacky things like assign to slices:

```
for l[::-1] in [l, l, l]: pass
```

or, subscriptions:

```
class Foo: a = 20
for Foo.a in range(2): pass
```

but I really have no idea why you'd want to do so.

This is a by-product of `for-loop`s essentially performing an assignment statement for every iteration, as stated in the reference:

> Each item in turn is assigned to the target list *using the standard rules for assignments* (see Assignment statements), and then the suite is executed.

So what the loop does is, it gets the iterator from the `expression_list` and performs an assignment to each of the values in the `target_list`. Essentially equivalent to the following `while` loop:

```
it = enumerate(l[:])
while True:
    try:
        i, l[i] = next(it)
        print(l[i])
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

`dis` can also show this behavior manifesting on the byte-code level. Using a slightly simplified version:

```
def _():
    for i, l[i] in enumerate(l[:]):
        pass
```

you'd get an output of:

```
dis(_)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              40 (to 43)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (enumerate)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (l)
              9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 BUILD_SLICE              2
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             22 GET_ITER
        >>   23 FOR_ITER                16 (to 42)
             26 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             29 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             32 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (l)
             35 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             38 STORE_SUBSCR

  3          39 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           23
        >>   42 POP_BLOCK
        >>   43 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             46 RETURN_VALUE
```

where the relevant assignment is performed right after the the `FOR_ITER` command:

```
             26 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             29 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             32 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (l)
             35 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             38 STORE_SUBSCR
```

unpacks the sequence and assigns it to `i` and `l[i]`.

If you also disassemble `dis('i, l[i] = (1, 2)')` you'll see that if you ignore the initial loading of the tuple `(1, 2)` and the returning of the value, the operations are exactly the same.

Comment: Isn't the issue here the sequence of interpreted assignment and therefore binding creation? Which makes the while example in itself sort of non-explanatory?

Comment: @pvg no no the issue that I was trying to highlight is the fact that there's an assignment going on ergo anything in `target_list` is allowed as the iteration variable for a `for-loop`. The `while` was written to show a friendly form of the sequence of commands executed and how it contains a hidden assignment.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I see what you're saying. I'm obviously suffering from python binding- and scope- Stockholm syndrome.

Comment: @pvg hah, then you can check out [this nice article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/) that explains the scoping situation in `for-loop`s nicely :-)